# When is $\{ X^{mk} \ : \ 0 \leq k \leq n-1\} $ a basis for $R[X]/(f)$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials

Let $R$ be a commutative ring and $f \in R[X]$ irreducible with degree $n$.
Let $m$ be an integer such that $0 \leq m \leq n-1$.
Can we say that
$$
\mathcal{B}\ := \ \{ X^{mk} \ : \  0 \leq k \leq n-1\}
$$ 
is a basis for $R[X]/(f)$?

I am not sure wheither the irreducibility of $f$ is necessary, neither wheither we need to add constraints on $R$ for the statement to be true. 
I would be glad to know something about that as well.

---

We only need to show that $\mathcal{B}$ is linearly independent.
Let us assume that it is *dependant* and try to obtain a contradiction.

Let us take a polynomial $g \neq 0$ of degree at most $n-1$  and assume that
$$
g(X^m)
\ = \ 
h(X)f(X)
\quad \quad 
\text{for some}
\quad
h \in R[X]
$$
We can assume that $g$ is irreducible.
Now I dont know how to go on.
I tried write out 
$f(X) =  \sum a_k X^k$ and 
$g(X) =  \sum b_k X^k$
but since $m$ is unknown the bookkeeping becomes hard.
Do you have a more elegant approach then this?

Comment: Why do these things in B span?

Comment: If they are independent they do right? the dimension is finite.

Comment: $R[X]/(f)$ is not necessarily a free $R$-module!